# Tableau - Generate a histogram where binning by "number of records" per [string ID field]

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset of events that I'm trying to build a histogram for. Each event has a user, and some other fields related to the event and the user.

I want to automatically create bins of the number of events per user, and show how many users fall in each bin. The idea is to visualize user engagement levels. (Ex: 30 users have less than X events, 100 users have between X and Y events, etc...). Maybe 5 total bins?

[This blog post](http://vizdiff.blogspot.com/2015/02/histograms-on-aggregated-measures.html) demonstrates how to do this by manually binning with a calculated field, but the number of events per user is going to shift over time and I don't want to have to constantly adjust the bins. There must be a way to automatically do this, but I'm struggling to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of that article. I don't know of anything for what you want in Tableau 8. Tableau 9 may have some features that allow us to do that. What you could do for now, is to have a bin for any number > N. This way you won't limit yourself. If it turns out that the last bin has got to many samples, you can always make smaller bins and push N higher.

Comment: I wrote up my solution (with a lot of screenshots) using Level of Detail Expressions which wasn't *exactly* what I was aiming for, but was a little bit  easier to update if the underlying data shifts than your Tableau 8 solution. Thanks for the push in the right direction!

http://www.ultravioletanalytics.com/2015/04/23/tableau-9-binning-by-aggregate-with-level-of-detail-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

Tableau 9 introduced a new type of calculation that is perfect for this situation

http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/2/introduction-level-detail-expressions-36655